# Rebrandly API in python

Tags: python

I'm using this Rebrandly API in python and I'm new to python so I'm struggling with it. I want to have all the links in a file.txt line by line converted into shortlink. I tried various methods but fails. Are there any possible solution for my problem?

file.txt :

https://link1.com

https://link2.com

https://link3.com

Here's the code :

```
url = "https://api.rebrandly.com/v1/links/new?destination=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com"

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "apikey": "removed"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please refrain from posting private credentials in your posts.   Please regenerate your apikey as your current apikey is no longer safe.   That said, what exactly are you having troubles with?  What methods did you try and failed with?  Please include pertinent information.

Answer (score 0):

I've divided the things you need to do into three steps.

**Step 1**: Read the links that you would like to short.

```py
with open('input_links.txt') as input_fp:
    lines = input_fp.readlines() # lines = ["https://link1.com", "https://link2.com", ...]
```

**Step 2**: Have a method to shorten the links from the API call.

```py
# Inspired from Rebrandly docs.
# Link: https://developers.rebrandly.com/docs.
import requests
import json


def shorten_link(destination):
    """
    Returns a short link if successful. Otherwise, an empty string.
    """

    headers = {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "apikey": "YOUR_API_KEY",
      "workspace": "YOUR_WORKSPACE_ID"
    }
    
    body = {
      "domain": { "fullName": "rebrand.ly" }
      "destination": destination,
    }
    
    r = requests.post(
        "https://api.rebrandly.com/v1/links", 
        data = json.dumps(body),
        headers=headers
    )
    
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        link = r.json()
        return link["shortUrl"]
    
    return ""
```

**Step 3**: Save the results into a file.

```py
with open('output_links.txt', 'w') as output_fp:
    for link in links:
      short_link = shorten_link(link)

    output_fp.write(f"{short_link}\n")
```